# Invalid identifier error - SQL*

Tags: sql, oracle

I am receiving this error:

> "Error at line 27 ORA-00904: "ACJS"."ACJ_ID": invalid identifier"

Any help on how to rectify would be greatly appreciated!

```
SELECT DC.ACJ_ID,
       DC.MCI_UNIQ_ID,
       DG.GENDER_COMMON_DESC,
       DR.RACE_COMMON_DESC,
       AD.ADDRESS_LINE_1,
       AD.ADDRESS_LINE_2,
       AD.CITY,
       AD.STATE,
       AD.ZIP_CD,
       AD.ZIP_CD_9,
       DC_RANK
  FROM DW_CLNTVIEW.FACT_CLIENT_WEEK_LATEST FCAS,
       DW.DIM_GENDER DG,
       DW.DIM_RACE DR,
       DW.DIM_ADDRESS AD,
       KLISA.MY_ACJ_IDS  ACJS,
       (SELECT ACJ_ID,
               MCI_UNIQ_ID,
               DENSE_RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY ACJ_ID ORDER BY END_DATE DESC, EFF_DATE DESC, MCI_UNIQ_ID DESC) ---REMOVE “MCI_UNIQ_ID DESC” TO ALLOW DUPLICATES ON ACJ_ID 
               DC_RANK
          FROM DW.DIM_CLIENT) DC
WHERE     FCAS.RACE_KEY = DR.RACE_KEY(+)
       AND FCAS.SRC_SYS_KEY(+) = 0
       AND FCAS.GENDER_KEY = DG.GENDER_KEY(+)
       AND FCAS.ADDRESS_KEY = AD.ADDRESS_KEY(+)
       AND DC.MCI_UNIQ_ID = FCAS.MCI_UNIQ_ID(+)
       AND ACJS.ACJ_ID = DC.ACJ_ID(+)
       AND DC_RANK(+) = 1;
```

Comment: *Please* use explicit `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN` syntax... this is really hard to follow...

Comment: Probably there is not a column named `ACJ_ID` on `KLISA.MY_ACJ_IDS`

Comment: @vercelli the column is named ACJS?

Comment: I don't understand. Are you asking me? Please edit your question and post the structure of `KLISA.MY_ACJ_IDS`